# $\int\limits_{-1/2}^{1/2}(\sin^{-1}(3x-4x^3)-\cos^{-1}(4x^3-3x))dx=$

Tags: definite-integrals

$\int\limits_{-1/2}^{1/2}(\sin^{-1}(3x-4x^3)-\cos^{-1}(4x^3-3x))dx=$

$(A)0\hspace{1cm}(B)\frac{-\pi}{2}\hspace{1cm}(C)\frac{\pi}{2}\hspace{1cm}(D)\frac{7\pi}{2}$

I tried and got the answer but my answer is not matching the options given.Is my method not correct?

$\int\limits_{-1/2}^{1/2}(\sin^{-1}(3x-4x^3)-\cos^{-1}(4x^3-3x))dx=\int\limits_{-1/2}^{1/2}(3\sin^{-1}(x)-3\cos^{-1}(x))dx$
$=3\int\limits_{-1/2}^{1/2}(\sin^{-1}(x)-\cos^{-1}(x))dx=3\int\limits_{-1/2}^{1/2}(\frac{\pi}{2}-2\cos^{-1}(x))dx=\frac{3\pi}{2}-6\int\limits_{-1/2}^{1/2}\cos^{-1}(x)dx$
$=\frac{3\pi}{2}+6\int\limits_{2\pi/3}^{\pi/3}t \sin t dt=\frac{-3\pi}{2}$

Comment: $\arcsin(a+b)\neq\arcsin a+\arcsin b$.

Comment: @Aretino,where have i used that?

Comment: The substitution $3x-4x^{3} \to x$ is incorrect

Comment: @diya Sorry, I had misread your work. However your change of variables in the integral is incorrect.

Comment: I think $\arccos(4x^3-3x)$ is not $3\arccos(x)$ in this interval. For the angle $\arccos(x)$ is not far from $90$ degrees, so multiplying by $3$ we get something much bigger than $\arccos(4x^3-3x)$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We use the facts that
$$\arccos(-x)=\pi-\arccos(x)$$
and
$$\arccos(x)+\arcsin(x)=\pi/2.$$
We have
\begin{align}
& \int_{-1/2}^{1/2}\left(\arcsin\left(3x-4x^3\right)-\arccos\left(4x^3-3x\right)\right)\mathrm{d}x \\
& \quad = \int_{-1/2}^{1/2}\left(\arcsin\left(3x-4x^3\right)-\pi+\arccos\left(3x-4x^3\right)\right)\mathrm{d}x \\
& \quad = \int_{-1/2}^{1/2}\left(-\pi+\pi/2\right)\mathrm{d}x=-\pi/2.
\end{align}

Comment: @Leucippus Thanks for the edit, it looks better now! I was hurry because of Ron Gordon's answer (+1 btw for another trig identity).

Comment: just trying to help, also good, clear and instructive answer.

Comment: Why on earth would my answer cause you to hurry yours?

Comment: @Ron Gordon I meant that I saw your answer while finishing writing mine, so I did not pay attention to the "elegance" of my answer. I do not answer when I see someone has posted something similar to what I want to write.

Answer (score 7):

Hint:

$$\arcsin{a} - \arccos{(-a)} = \arcsin{a}+\arcsin{(-a)} - \frac{\pi}{2} = - \frac{\pi}{2}$$